# Integrate R in webapplication

Tags: angularjs, r, analysis

I would like to develop a webapplication which is able to analyze data using R. How can I integrate R into a webapplication, so I can use a library of R functions?

The webapplication is written in angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course YES. The simplest and the most straightforward way would be using Shiny:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/

At first, have a glance on their gallery of examples.

P.S. You clearly asked about web applications, but if you'll ever need to embed R code & diagrams in documents to make them **dynamic and responsive to data changes**, you could use combo of: [R markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) and [knitr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html).